# Recursive processing of list elements in LISP

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, lisp

Here is a task: a list is given, some of the elements are also lists. It's nescessary to replace the nested lists with the sum of the numbers in them, if all of them are *even*, using **recursion**. For example:

```
(1 2 NIL (2 4 6) 5 7) -> (1 2 NIL 12 5 7)
```

if the parent list matches the condition after the transformation:

```
(2 2 (4 4) (2 2)) -> (2 2 8 4) -> 16
```

Now i have the following code:

```
;; check  for all list elements are even 
(defun is-even-list (lst)
    (cond ((null lst) t)
        ((and (numberp (car lst)) (evenp (car lst))) (is-even-list (cdr lst)))      
        (t nil)
    )
)

;; list summing 
(defun sum-list (lst)
    (cond ((null lst) 0)
        (t (+ (car lst) (sum-list (cdr lst))))
    )
) 

;; main func 
(defun task (lst)
    (cond ((null lst) nil)
        ((atom (car lst)) (cons (car lst) (task (cdr lst))))
        ((is-even-list (car lst)) (cons (list (sum-list (car lst))) (task (cdr lst))))
        (t (cons (task (car lst)) (task (cdr lst))))
    )
)
```

But now it processes only the “lowest” level of the list if it exists:

```
(2 4)               -> (2 4)
(2 (2 4 6) 6)       -> (2 12 6)
(2 (4 (6 8) 10) 12) -> (2 (4 14 10) 12)
(2 (4 6) (8 10) 12) -> (2 10 18 12)
```

How can i change this code to get "full" processing?

Comment: no, following your specs logically, it should be `(2 2 (4 4) (2 2)) -> (2 2 8 4) -> 16`. the way you have it, it is guaranteed to *not* match the condition after the processing: `(8)` is not even. it is  not even a number.

Comment: Sorry, i used brackets  to point to summing result, not in meaning that result must be single element list. I removed them.

Comment: ok, still it must be `(2 2 (4 4) (2 2)) -> (2 2 8 4) -> 16`, not `(16)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's  definitely not the best solution but it works:

```
(defun is-even-list (lst)
    (cond ((null lst) t)
        ((and (numberp (car lst)) (evenp (car lst))) (is-even-list (cdr lst)))      
        (t nil)
    )
)

(defun sum-list (lst)
    (cond ((null lst) 0)
        (t (+ (car lst) (sum-list (cdr lst))))
    )
) 

(defun test (lst)   
    (dotimes (i (list-length lst))      
        (cond           
            ((not (atom (nth i lst))) (setf (nth i lst) (test (nth i lst))))
        )
    )

    (cond       
        ((is-even-list lst) (setf lst (sum-list lst)))
        ((not (is-even-list lst)) (setf lst lst))       
    )   
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to show some improvements on your own answer.

First, use conventional formatting: no dangling parentheses, bodies indented two spaces, other argument forms aligned.  Use appropriate line breaks.

```
(defun is-even-list (lst)
  (cond ((null lst) t)
        ((and (numberp (car lst))
              (evenp (car lst)))
         (is-even-list (cdr lst)))            
        (t nil)))

(defun sum-list (lst)
  (cond ((null lst) 0)
        (t (+ (car lst)
              (sum-list (cdr lst))))))

(defun test (lst)
  (dotimes (i (list-length lst))
    (cond ((not (atom (nth i lst)))
           (setf (nth i lst) (test (nth i lst))))))
  (cond ((is-even-list lst) (setf lst (sum-list lst)))
        ((not (is-even-list lst)) (setf lst lst))))
```

The first function checks two things: that every element is a number, and that every element is even.  In this context, the first condition mainly means: no sublists.

```
(defun flat-all-even-p (list)
  (and (every #'numberp list)
       (every #'even list)))
```

The second function sums a list and assumes that all elements are numbers (sublists would signal an error here).

```
(defun sum (list)
  (reduce #'+ list))
```

The third function does not *test*, it *sums*.  Note that it only accidentally returns the answer, since `setf` returns the value it sets.  Another problem is that you do index lookup on lists in a loop, which is very inefficient.  Finally, you modify the list you were given, which will surprise your caller.

```
(defun sum-if-all-even (tree)
  (if (listp tree)
      (let ((recursed-tree (mapcar #'sum-if-all-even tree)))
        (if (flat-all-even-p recursed-tree)
            (sum recursed-tree)
            recursed-tree))
      tree)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which I think meets the requirements of the question: recursively sum a list each element of which is either an even number or a list meeting the same requirement.  It also does this making only a single pass over the structure it is trying to sum.  For large lists, it relies on tail-call elimination in the implementation which probably is always true now but is not required to be.  `sum-list-loop` could be turned into something explicitly iterative if not.

```
(defun sum-list-if-even (l)
  ;; Sum a list if all its elements are either even numbers or lists
  ;; for which this function returns an even number.  If that's not
  ;; true return the list.  This assumes that the list is proper and
  ;; elements are numbers or lists which meet the same requirement but
  ;; it does not check this in cases where it gives up for other
  ;; reasons first: (sum-list-if-even '(2 "")) signals a type error
  ;; (but (sum-list-if-even '(1 "")) fails to do so)
  (labels ((sum-list-loop (tail sum)
             (etypecase tail
               (null sum)               ;all the elements of '() are even numbers
               (cons
                (let ((first (first tail)))
                  (etypecase first
                    (integer
                     ;; Easy case: an integer is either an even number
                     ;; or we give up immediately
                     (if (evenp first)
                         (sum-list-loop (rest tail) (+ sum first))
                       ;; give up immediately
                       l))
                    (list
                     ;; rerurse on the car ...
                     (let ((try (sum-list-if-even first)))
                       ;; ... and check to see what we got to know if
                       ;; we should recurse on the cdr
                       (if (not (eq try first))
                           (sum-list-loop (rest tail) (+ sum try))
                         l)))))))))
    (sum-list-loop l 0)))
```

Comment: Shouldn’t `(sum-list-if-even '(1 (2 4) 6))` return `(1 6 6)`? I get `(1 (2 4) 6)`.

Comment: @Knuto: it should return `(1 (2 4) 6)` according to its specification: the list is not a list all of whose elements are either even or lists which meet the same requirement.  That may not be what the problem was asking for but that's how I read it and what the function is designed to do.